# HTML file: add annotations through IHTMLDocument

Tags: c++, com, winapi, dom

I need to add "annotations" to existing HTML documents - best in the form of string property values I can read & write by name.

Apparently (to me), meta elements in the header seem to be the common way - i.e. adding/modifying elements like

```
<head>
  <meta name="unique-id_property-name"  content="property-value"/>
  ...
</head>
```

**Question 1:** Ist that "acceptable" / ok, or is there a better way to add meta data?

I have a little previous experience with getting/mut(il)ating HTML contents through the `document` in an web browser control. For this task, I've already loaded the HTML document into a `HTMLDocument` object, but I'm not sure how to go on:

```
// what I have:

IHTMLDocument2Ptr doc;
doc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(HTMLDocument));
IPersistFile pf = doc;
pf->Load(fileName, STGM_READ);  

// ... what now?
```

**Questions 2:** Should I be using anything else than `HTMLDocument`?

**Questions 3..N:**
How do I get the `head` element?
How do I get the value of a meta element with a given name?
How do I set the value of a meta element (adding the item if and only if it doesn't exist yet)?

`doc->all` returns a collection of all tags, which I can enumerate even though count returns 0. I could scan that for `head`, then scan that for all `meta` where the name starts with a certain string, etc. - but this feels very clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have enough experience working with HTML using C++. 
I am not sure if this answers your question, but you could do the following

1. enum all elements using doc->all
2. for each IHtmlElement you can compare the tagname to meta (use IHtmlElement::get_tagName)
3. for these meta tags you can get and set property using IHtmlElement::getAttribute and setAttribute methods)

Or

1. Write a Javascript function that accepts a property name and value. This should be able to update the meta tag you have
2. You can then get the script object using IHtmlDocument2::get_script as IDispatch
3. Use this script dispatch to Invoke your javascript function.